# Dispatched lambda not reading the correct addresses?

Tags: c++, std, shared-ptr, glib, glibmm

For some context, I'm trying to build a GUI application, and at some point I need to build a widget and retrieve some data (in another thread, but for now I'm doing it in the main thread), this data will be stored in an object wrapped by a `shared_ptr`.

The `shared_ptr` contents will be accessed on the main thread by a lambda executed by a `Glib::Dispatcher`, for some reason however, it seems that the `shared_ptr` gets deleted before (or once) the dispatcher gets called.

*Note that the `shared_ptr` is tied to the lifetime of the class, even though it is initialized in the constructor.*

A bit of sample code:

**Header File**

```
class ExploreView : public Gtk::Box
{
public:
    ExploreView(std::shared_ptr<Gtk::Window> parent_window);
public:
    // Explore Object
    std::shared_ptr<backend::Explore> explore; // The pointer!
    // Featured Shows Previews
    std::shared_ptr<Glib::Dispatcher> featured_callback;
};
```

**Snippet from the class constructor**

```
featured_callback = std::make_shared<Glib::Dispatcher>();
featured_callback->connect([this]() {
    std::cout << "Dispatched!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "USE COUNT: " << explore.use_count() << std::endl;
});

explore = std::make_shared<backend::Explore>();
std::cout << "USE COUNT: " << explore.use_count() << std::endl;
featured_callback->emit();
```

As you can see, I'm allocating the `Glib::Dispatcher`, connect a `lambda` to it, and then writing inside some dumb code to print a string and check the use count of the `shared_ptr`.

This code is not called yet.

Afterwards I'm initializing the `explore` `shared_ptr`, printing the use count *(which is 1, as expected)* and finally I'm calling the `Glib::Dispatcher` (the lambda that I *"connected"* to it previously.

I would expect the lambda to happily print `1`, instead it `segfault`s. But I can't understand why, the pointer lifetime should be tied to the class, not the constructor, if that's even the problem to begin with.

**This behavior seems weird to me, so for testing only I switched to a raw C pointer.**

Updated code as sample:

**Updated header file**

```
class ExploreView : public Gtk::Box
{
public:
    ExploreView(std::shared_ptr<Gtk::Window> parent_window);
public:
    // Explore Object
    backend::Explore* explore;
    // Featured Shows Previews
    std::shared_ptr<Glib::Dispatcher> featured_callback;
};
```

**Updated snippet from class constructor**

```
featured_callback = std::make_shared<Glib::Dispatcher>();
featured_callback->connect([this]() {
    std::cout << "Dispatched!" << std::endl;
    // This is a vector of which size is always 10
    std::cout << "Retrieved size: " << explore->featured_anime_ids.size() << std::endl;
});

explore = new backend::Explore();
featured_callback->emit();
```

This didn't work either.

Consider that the `Explore` object contains the member `featured_anime_ids` which is a `vector<int>` of which size is always `10`.

For some reason, when accessing it from the dispatched lambda, I always get size `18446743979220271125` no matter how many times I run it. Trying to allocate any buffer from the dispatched lambda results in a segmentation fault.

I also tried printing the address of the `shared_ptr` from outside the dispatched lambda and from within the dispatched lambda, and I noticed that the address changed. Using the debugger, I also saw at some point the content of the pointer changed.

**While writing I did some more testing with the debugger.**

It seems that the buffer stays in memory as it should, but the `shared_ptr` is changing it's address (and so I suppose also the raw pointer) making the lambda read and write to random buffers in memory and therefore rightfully going into segault.

But I do not understand what is causing this behavior.

I'm also not sure of what other testing I could do, any help is immensely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your `Dispatcher` object is outliving your `ExploreView` object.  You're capturing `this`, but by the time you use it the object that `this` points to is gone.  There's no way to tell for sure from the code you've provided though.  A [mcve] would help.

Comment: I thought of this, but there a couple of thigs that don't add up (thinking about it now, something that I should probably have written on the question).
The ExploreView object never dies until the application closes, and other object within ExploreView already use this same apporoach without issues, so it would be weird for object lifetime to be the issue, I will try to come up with a reproducible sample that isn't too large though.

Comment: Actually, no, you're right. The object does go out of scope, though I'm not sure of the reason why. `ExploreView` is stored in a `unique_ptr`, but by storing it into a `ExploreView*` and by never freeing the code works, since the object never goes out of scope. It's an ugly workaround, but at least now I know what the issue is, thank you!